# Angular9 / Typescript apex caracter ' VS ` (Backtick or Accento Grave)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this pipe.ts class:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'discount'
})
export class DiscountFormatterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  // ?: should means that the variable is not mandatory
  transform(value: number, discount: number, is_special?: boolean, args?: any): any {
    if(!Number.isInteger(value)) return value;

    let text = String(value);
    let discountedValue = value - discount;
    text = `You save <del>${value}</del> <b>${discountedValue}</b>`;
    debugger;
    
    return text;
  }
  

}
```

I discovered that it is different to write:

```
text = `You save <del>${value}</del> <b>${discountedValue}</b>`;
```

instead of:

```
text = 'You save <del>${value}</del> <b>${discountedValue}</b>';
```

changing apex type. The second syntax doesn't work. What change between `` and '' ? What is the real name of  `, how I can make it without do copy paste and what are his funcionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings surrounded with <kbd>`</kbd> are template literals, which allow you to embed expressions.

Strings surrounded with <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd> are string literals, and do not allow embedded expressions.

```
var age = 12;

var s1 = `I am ${age} years old`; //I am 12 years old
var s2 = 'I am ${age} years old'; //I am ${age} years old
```

See the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more information. They're quite handy, and can help you reduce unsightly string concatenation in your code.

```
var s3 = `Next year I will be ${age + 1} years old`; //Next year I will be 13 years old
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. But do you know which keyboard combination can I use to do it?

Comment: On US keyboards, it's on the same key as the ~ (tilde) character, immediately to the left of the number row. If you're using a non-US keyboard, I'm afraid I don't know, but this post may help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backticks-for-keyboard-without-backticks/61483. ALT+numpad9+numpad6 may do the trick. It's technically called the "grave" or "grave accent," but you'll more frequently hear it called "backtick" or "backquote."

Comment: Thank you, found it! http://geckosoft.it/blog/come-digitare-il-catattere-backtick-accento-grave-e-tilde-su-windows-utilizzando-una-tastiera-italiana-senza-tastierino-numerico using ASCII: ALT+96